# Civi isn't finding matching contacts when importing contributions

Tags: import, contributions

I'm trying to import contributions from another source, and Civi gives me a "no matching contact found" error for each record. I've checked my csv data, my Civi data, my field mapping, and my unsupervised dedupe rule (all of these are individuals).

I can copy the email address text from the csv file, search for it in civi, and find the correct person and only the correct person. But, when my unsupervised dedupe rule is set to email only, I still get "no matching contact found for ([email address that is in fact in the database] )" when I import.

What else should I check?

Comment: Are you using the CiviCRM ID (Internal Contact ID) as a field in the import file?

Comment: Can you confirm what other fields you are importing. as joe implies if you have other fields like Internal or External ID then I think Civi import my favour that over the email match specified by the Unsupervised Rule

Comment: No ID fields in the import. When I've imported contributions before, I've used ID fields, but that ends up being a hassle and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Here are all the fields I am importing:
Transaction ID
Receive Date
Total Amount
Email (match to contact)
Contribution Source
Fee Amount
Net Amount
Payment Instrument
Note
Financial Type
And on some attempts, I've also used First Name, Last Name

Comment: Maybe add screenshot of screen 1 and screent 2. This is import not update? You are importing as the correct Contact Type?

Comment: can you try using a CiviCRM ID match for one of the records and not email and see if that transaction works.

Comment: Petednz - Yes I am importing as individuals, and am importing new contribution records (not updating).  pkeogan - Good idea. I included the civiID for one of the records, and that record imported correctly. The others now returned the error "Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: contact_id", which makes sense since the ID will override the unsupervised rule.